# I'm seeing : used in code

Tags: javascript

I'm seeing `:` used in JavaScript a good bit and I can not figure out what exactly what its doing. Is it naming something? For example is the function being named onSave? Example is below.

```
 onSave: function() {
        var properties = this.getFormData(),
            request = this.wfsBody("usa", "usa:pecotest", "geom",                  
            properties);
            console.log(request);
            this.makeRequest(request);enter code here
```

Comment: Typically `:` is used to separate property from value, however without more context it's hard to say.

Comment: In an *object literal*, the colon `:` separates a property and it's value

Comment: For the record, what it's being used for "in java a good bit" actually doesn't have anything to do with JavaScript - they're two different languages

Comment: if you look to the left/up you'll find a `{` somewhere...

Comment: I think you mean `JavaScript` and not `Java`, right?

Comment: `Java` is to `Javascript` as `car` is to `carpet`

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Wales is to New South Wales...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are, as far as I know, four uses of <kbd>:</kbd> in JavaScript. The ternary operator, switch statements, [labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label), and part of JavaScript object creation.

```
// if a, then f is b. Otherwise it is C.
var f = a? b: c; 
// This creates an object. You can now look at the object's `name` property.
var obj = {name: val}

switch(foo)
{
   case 1:
     // this only happens if foo === 1
     break;
}

top: // this is a label
for (i = 0; items.length; i++)
  for (j = 0; j < tests.length; i++)
    if (!tests[j].pass(items[i])){
      allPass = false;
      break top; // breaks the outermost loop.
    }
```

You'll see this also in JSON, which is JavaScript object notation:

```
{
    "foo": 1,
    "bar": [2,3],
    "baz": {
         "bat": 4
    }
}
```

That is an object where

```
obj.foo === 1
obj.bar[0] === 2
obj.bar[1] === 3
obj.baz.bat === 4
```

The most common use, and certainly what most people expect when they see the above code, is that an object is being created with a property "onStart" which is a function defined as above.

Comment: don't forget labels: `see: alert('hello')`

Comment: @dandavis That is a markup question.

Comment: @dandavis It isn't JavaScript. It's markup.

Comment: @dandavis You are quite correct. I was confused by the "alert('hello');" thinking you meant something like `<a href="javascript:alert('hello');">`, which is markup.

Answer (score 1):

`:` is used as an `=` in an object - separating the object property from its value. Objects can also have functions as values. So what you're seeing is:

```
var obj = {
onSave: function(){}
}
```

could also be `obj.onSave = function(){}`

Comment: thanks man you nailed it for me. I took a look around some more code and figured out that what I'm looking at is objects for a class file. I'm just use to seeing it differently.